# computing determinant of a matrix (nxn) recursively

Tags: python, recursion

I'm about to write some code that computes the determinant of a square matrix (nxn), using the Laplace algorithm (Meaning recursive algorithm) as written [Wikipedia's **Laplace Expansion**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion).

I already have the class `Matrix`, which includes **init**, **setitem**, **getitem**, **repr** and all the things I need to compute the determinant (including `minor(i,j)`).

So I've tried the code below:

```
def determinant(self,i=0)  # i can be any of the matrix's rows
    assert isinstance(self,Matrix)
    n,m = self.dim()    # Q.dim() returns the size of the matrix Q
    assert n == m
    if (n,m) == (1,1):
        return self[0,0]
    det = 0
    for j in range(n):
        det += ((-1)**(i+j))*(self[i,j])*((self.minor(i,j)).determinant())
    return det
```

As expected, in every recursive call, `self` turns into an appropriate minor. But when coming back from the recursive call, it doesn't change back to it's original matrix. 
This causes trouble when in the `for` loop (when the function arrives at `(n,m)==(1,1)`, this one value of the matrix is returned, but in the `for` loop, `self` is still a 1x1 matrix - why?)

Comment: Does `self.minor(i,j)` actually transform `self`?

Comment: yes. you right. i'll change that and check again. thank you

Comment: I'd advise against using `assert`s like this. The first one (`assert isinstance(self, Matrix)`) doesn't do anything - it's a method on `Matrix`, so you know for certain that `self` is a `Matrix`. The second one would work better with something like `if n != m: raise ValueError("Matrix is not square")` because the exception is more specific about the problem (and can be caught more easily).

Comment: Also, do you really want the user to be able to pass in `i` as a parameter? The determinant is a property of a matrix, independent of which row or column you take it along. So it doesn't really make sense to let the user choose (since the result will be the same no matter what they pick).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your `minor` returns the a new object and not a reference to your original matrix object? I used your exact determinant method and implemented a `minor` method for your class, and it works fine for me.

Below is a quick/dirty implementation of your matrix class, since I don't have your implementation. For brevity I have chosen to implement it for square matrices only, which in this case shouldn't matter as we are dealing with determinants. Pay attention to `det` method, that is the same as yours, and `minor` method (the rest of the methods are there to facilitate the implementation and testing):

```
class matrix:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.data = [0.0 for i in range(n*n)]
        self.dim = n
    @classmethod
    def rand(self, n):
        import random
        a = matrix(n)
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                a[i,j] = random.random()
        return a
    @classmethod
    def eye(self, n):
        a = matrix(n)
        for i in range(n):
            a[i,i] = 1.0
        return a        
    def __repr__(self):
        n = self.dim
        for i in range(n):
            print str(self.data[i*n: i*n+n])
        return ''    
    def __getitem__(self,(i,j)):
        assert i < self.dim and j < self.dim
        return self.data[self.dim*i + j]
    def __setitem__(self, (i, j), val):
        assert i < self.dim and j < self.dim
        self.data[self.dim*i + j] = float(val)
    #
    def minor(self, i,j):
        n = self.dim
        assert i < n and j < n
        a = matrix(self.dim-1)
        for k in range(n):
            for l in range(n):
                if k == i or l == j: continue
                if k < i:
                    K = k
                else:
                    K = k-1
                if l < j:
                    L = l
                else:
                    L = l-1
                a[K,L] = self[k,l]
        return a
    def det(self, i=0):
        n = self.dim    
        if n == 1:
            return self[0,0]
        d = 0
        for j in range(n):
            d += ((-1)**(i+j))*(self[i,j])*((self.minor(i,j)).det())
        return d
    def __mul__(self, v):
        n = self.dim
        a = matrix(n)
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                a[i,j] = v * self[i,j]
        return a
    __rmul__ = __mul__
```

Now for testing

```
import numpy as np
a = matrix(3)
# same matrix from the Wikipedia page
a[0,0] = 1
a[0,1] = 2
a[0,2] = 3
a[1,0] = 4
a[1,1] = 5
a[1,2] = 6
a[2,0] = 7
a[2,1] = 8
a[2,2] = 9
a.det()   # returns 0.0
# trying with numpy the same matrix
A = np.array(a.data).reshape([3,3])
print np.linalg.det(A)  # returns -9.51619735393e-16
```

The residual in case of numpy is because it calculates the determinant through (Gaussian) elimination method rather than the Laplace expansion. You can also compare the results on random matrices to see that the difference between your determinant function and numpy's doesn't grow beyond `float` precision:

```
import numpy as np
a = 10*matrix.rand(4)
A = np.array( a.data ).reshape([4,4])
print (np.linalg.det(A) - a.det())/a.det() # varies between zero and 1e-14
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

def smaller_matrix(original_matrix,row, column):
    for ii in range(len(original_matrix)):
        new_matrix=np.delete(original_matrix,ii,0)
        new_matrix=np.delete(new_matrix,column,1)
        return new_matrix


def determinant(matrix):
    """Returns a determinant of a matrix by recursive method."""
    (r,c) = matrix.shape 
    if r != c:
        print("Error!Not a square matrix!")
        return None
    elif r==2:
        simple_determinant = matrix[0][0]*matrix[1][1]-matrix[0][1]*matrix[1][0]
        return simple_determinant
    else: 
        answer=0
        for j in range(r):
            cofactor = (-1)**(0+j) * matrix[0][j] * determinant(smaller_matrix(matrix, 0, j))
            answer+= cofactor
        return answer



#test the function
#Only works for numpy.array input
np.random.seed(1)
matrix=np.random.rand(5,5)

determinant(matrix)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's the function in python 3.

Note: I used a one-dimensional list to house the matrix and the size array is the amount of rows or columns in the square array. It uses a recursive algorithm to find the determinant.

```
def solve(matrix,size):
    c = []
    d = 0
    print_matrix(matrix,size)
    if size == 0:
        for i in range(len(matrix)):
            d = d + matrix[i]
        return d
    elif len(matrix) == 4:
        c = (matrix[0] * matrix[3]) - (matrix[1] * matrix[2])
        print(c)
        return c
    else:
        for j in range(size):
            new_matrix = []
            for i in range(size*size):
                if i % size != j and i > = size:
                    new_matrix.append(matrix[i])

            c.append(solve(new_matrix,size-1) * matrix[j] * ((-1)**(j+2)))

        d = solve(c,0)
        return d
```

Answer (score -1):

i posted this code because i couldn't fine it on the internet, how to solve n*n determinant using only standard library.
the purpose is to share it with those who will find it useful.
i started by calculating the submatrix Ai related to a(0,i).
and i used recursive determinant to make it short.

```
  def submatrix(M, c):
    B = [[1] * len(M) for i in range(len(M))]


    for l in range(len(M)):
        for k in range(len(M)):
            B[l][k] = M[l][k]

    B.pop(0)

    for i in range(len(B)):
        B[i].pop(c)
    return B


def det(M):
    X = 0
    if len(M) != len(M[0]):
        print('matrice non carrée')
    else:
        if len(M) <= 2:
            return M[0][0] * M[1][1] - M[0][1] * M[1][0]
        else:
            for i in range(len(M)):
                X = X + ((-1) ** (i)) * M[0][i] * det(submatrix(M, i))
    return X
```

sorry for not commenting before guys  :)
if you need any further explanation don't hesitate to ask .

Comment: Posting code-only answers without comment or explanation as to how it solves the problem is a discouraged practice on SO.

Answer (score -1):

use Sarrus' Rule (non recursive method)
example on below link is in Javascript, but easily can be written in python
https://github.com/apanasara/Faster_nxn_Determinant