# Determinant in Fortran95

Tags: recursion, matrix, fortran, gfortran, determinants

This code in fortran calculates the determinant of a nxn matrix using the laplacian formula (expansion by minors). I understand fully how this process works.

But could somebody give me an insight into how the following code operates over, say a given iteration, this section of the code contains the recursive function determinant(matrix) - assume some nxn matrix is read in and passed through and another function to call the cofactor. There are aspects of the code I understand but its the recursion that is confusing me profoundly. I've tried to run through step by step with a 3x3 matrix but to no avail.

```
! Expansion of determinants using Laplace formula
recursive function determinant(matrix) result(laplace_det)
real, dimension(:,:) :: matrix
integer :: msize(2), i, n
real :: laplace_det, det
real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: cf

msize = shape(matrix) 
n = msize(1)          

if (n .eq. 1) then  
  det = matrix(1,1)
else
  det = 0    
  do i=1, n  
    allocate(cf(n-1, n-1))     
    cf = cofactor(matrix, i, 1)
    det = det + ((-1)**(i+1))* matrix(i,1) * determinant(cf)
    deallocate(cf)
  end do        
end if
laplace_det = det
end function determinant       

 function cofactor(matrix, mI, mJ)
  real, dimension(:,:) :: matrix
  integer :: mI, mJ
  integer :: msize(2), i, j, k, l, n
  real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: cofactor
  msize = shape(matrix)
  n = msize(1)

  allocate(cofactor(n-1, n-1))
  l=0
  k = 1
  do i=1, n
   if (i .ne. mI) then
     l = 1
     do j=1, n
       if (j .ne. mJ) then
         cofactor(k,l) = matrix(i,j)
         l = l+ 1
       end if
     end do
     k = k+ 1
   end if
  end do
return
end function cofactor
```

The main section im struggling with is these two calls and the operation of the respective cofactor calculation.

```
cf = cofactor(matrix, i, 1)
det = det + ((-1)**(i+1))* matrix(i,1) * determinant(cf)
```

Any input for an explanation would be greatly appreciated (like i said an example of one iteration). This is my first post in stack-overflow as most of my question reside in mathstack (as you can probably tell by the mathematical nature of the question). Although I do have experience programming, the concept of recursion (especially in this example) is really boggling my mind.

If any edits are required please go ahead, im not familiar with the etiquette on stack overflow.

Comment: Maybe it is useful to add the general tag "fortran". Also, I'm wondering which of the following two is the source of difficulty/confusion: (1) handling of allocatable arrays in Fortran, (2) basic behavior of recursion functions in Fortran (as illustrated by [Fibonacci](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Fortran)).

Comment: I understand the use of allocatable arrays in Fortran, as far as I'm aware they essentially allow for a dynamic assignment of array size. Although I fail to see (although it clearly works) how the recursion of the `determinant(cf)` yeilds us with the correct value at each recursive iteration. I've tried following the code on pen and paper for just one iteration say `i=1` in the `recursive function determinant (matrix)` but i just get lost in the cofactor function.

Comment: I think the `cofactor()` function builds a sub-array from a given array by removing the mI-th row and the mJ-th column of the passed matrix, so `cf` is a 5x5 array if `matrix` is 6x6 array, for example. The obtained `cf` is then passed to `determinant()` as `determinant(cf)`, which will be evaluated "freshly" (i.e., independently of the current call of determinant()). So it is something like calling more and more independent functions with the same name. (Sorry if my explanation is poor...)

Comment: Hmmm I will speak to a proffessor about this on monday, what you said makes perfect sense and I have followed it up to this point but the workings dont check out (ill double check). Also I would be interested to know why i was downvoted (from 1 to 0). I would have preffered constructive criticism so as not to repeat the same mistake. I did state in my initial post that this was my first entry on stack overflow. Regardless thank you for your help, roygvib it has enhanced my understanding of the problem somewhat.

Comment: I did some tests using small matrices and it seems the code is working OK (although double precision would probably be better for more precision...). Also, you can find more info by googling for "determinant recursive" (e.g., [C](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/determinant/), [Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510111/computing-determinant-of-a-matrix-nxn-recursively), and [Fortran](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Matrix_arithmetic) <= This last one seems simpler than your code.) If not clear, please feel free to get back.

Comment: As for down votes, I don't think it is necessary to worry so much, because sometime it simply implies "off topic". For example, a question for numerical algorithms may be better suited to [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). And one more comment is that, the recursive algorithm is very inefficient for large matrices (O(N!) vs O(N^3) via LU factorization etc? Please check Wiki.)

Comment: This seems a lot simpler too me although I would very much like you to explain this section of code to me `b(:, :(i-1)) = a(2:, :i-1) b(:, i:) = a(2:, i+1:)`. I notice that the recursive function start by defining b as size `(n-1)(n-1)` clearly we want to find the determinant of this minor given an nxn matrix. Also is this code able to find the determinant for any nxn matrix? Thank you very much for your help again roygvib.

Comment: Also I am aware of algorithm complexity I will have to analyse that after I have finished understanding this code I know this method of O(N!) but thank you regardless, and for your point on downvotes ill take that on board, i probably could have even posted this in mathstack given fortran is manly used for computational mathematics, or large numerical procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us suppose that we pass the following 3x3 matrix to `determinant()`:

```
2 9 4
7 5 3
6 1 8
```

In the routine, the following two lines are executed iteratively for `i = 1,2,3`:

```
cf = cofactor(matrix, i, 1)
det = det + ((-1)**(i+1))* matrix(i,1) * determinant(cf)
```

which corresponds to the Laplace expansion with respect to the first column. More specifically, one passes the above 3x3 `matrix` to `cofactor()` to get a 2x2 sub-matrix  by removing the `i`-th row and 1st column of the `matrix`. The obtained 2x2 sub-matrix (`cf`) is then passed to `determinant()` in the next line to calculate the co-factor corresponding to this sub-matrix. So, in this first iterations we are trying to calculate

[image]

Note here that the three determinants in the right-hand side are yet to be calculated by subsequent calls of determinant(). Let us consider one such subsequent call, e.g. for `i=1`. We are passing the following sub-matrix (stored in `cf`)

```
5 3
1 8
```

to `determinant()`. Then, the same procedure as described above is repeated again and independently of the Laplace expansion for the parent 3x3 matrix. That is, the determinant() now iterates over `i=1,2` and tries to calculate

[image]

Note that the `i` in this subsequent call is different from the `i` of the previous call; they are all local variables living inside a particular call of a routine and are totally independent from each other. Also note that the index of dummy array argument (like `matrix(:,:)`) always start from `1` in Fortran (unless otherwise specified). This kind of operations are repeated until the size of the sub-matrix becomes `1`.

But in practice, I believe that the easiest way to understand this kind of code is to   write intermediate data and track the actual flow of data/routines. For example, we can insert a lot of `print` statements as

```
module mymod
    implicit none
contains

recursive function determinant(matrix) result(laplace_det)
    real :: matrix(:,:)
    integer :: i, n, p, q
    real :: laplace_det, det
    real, allocatable :: cf(:,:)

    n = size(matrix, 1) 

    !***** output *****   
    print "(a)", "Entering determinant() with matrix = "
    do p = 1, n
        print "(4x,100(f3.1,x))", ( matrix( p, q ), q=1,n )
    enddo

    if (n == 1) then  
        det = matrix(1,1)
    else
        det = 0
        do i = 1, n  
            allocate( cf(n-1, n-1) )
            cf = cofactor( matrix, i, 1 )

            !***** output *****
            print "(4x,a,i0,a,i0,a)", "Getting a ", &
                    n-1, "-by-", n-1, " sub-matrix from cofactor():"
            do p = 1, n-1
                print "(8x, 100(f3.1,x))", ( cf( p, q ), q=1,n-1 )
            enddo

            print "(4x,a)", "and passing it to determinant()."

            det = det + ((-1)**(i+1))* matrix( i, 1 ) * determinant( cf )
            deallocate(cf)
        end do
    end if

    laplace_det = det

    !***** output *****
    print *, "  ---> Returning det = ", det
end function

function cofactor(matrix, mI, mJ)
    .... (same as the original code)
end function

end module

program main
    use mymod
    implicit none
    real :: a(3,3), det

    a( 1, : ) = [ 2.0, 9.0, 4.0 ]
    a( 2, : ) = [ 7.0, 5.0, 3.0 ]
    a( 3, : ) = [ 6.0, 1.0, 8.0 ]

    det = determinant( a )
    print "(a, es30.20)", "Final det = ", det
end program
```

then the output clearly shows how the data are processed:

```
Entering determinant() with matrix = 
    2.0 9.0 4.0
    7.0 5.0 3.0
    6.0 1.0 8.0
    Getting a 2-by-2 sub-matrix from cofactor():
        5.0 3.0
        1.0 8.0
    and passing it to determinant().
Entering determinant() with matrix = 
    5.0 3.0
    1.0 8.0
    Getting a 1-by-1 sub-matrix from cofactor():
        8.0
    and passing it to determinant().
Entering determinant() with matrix = 
    8.0
   ---> Returning det =    8.0000000    
    Getting a 1-by-1 sub-matrix from cofactor():
        3.0
    and passing it to determinant().
Entering determinant() with matrix = 
    3.0
   ---> Returning det =    3.0000000    
   ---> Returning det =    37.000000    
    Getting a 2-by-2 sub-matrix from cofactor():
        9.0 4.0
        1.0 8.0
    and passing it to determinant().
Entering determinant() with matrix = 
    9.0 4.0
    1.0 8.0
    Getting a 1-by-1 sub-matrix from cofactor():
        8.0
    and passing it to determinant().
Entering determinant() with matrix = 
    8.0
   ---> Returning det =    8.0000000    
    Getting a 1-by-1 sub-matrix from cofactor():
        4.0
    and passing it to determinant().
Entering determinant() with matrix = 
    4.0
   ---> Returning det =    4.0000000    
   ---> Returning det =    68.000000    
    Getting a 2-by-2 sub-matrix from cofactor():
        9.0 4.0
        5.0 3.0
    and passing it to determinant().
Entering determinant() with matrix = 
    9.0 4.0
    5.0 3.0
    Getting a 1-by-1 sub-matrix from cofactor():
        3.0
    and passing it to determinant().
Entering determinant() with matrix = 
    3.0
   ---> Returning det =    3.0000000    
    Getting a 1-by-1 sub-matrix from cofactor():
        4.0
    and passing it to determinant().
Entering determinant() with matrix = 
    4.0
   ---> Returning det =    4.0000000    
   ---> Returning det =    7.0000000    
   ---> Returning det =   -360.00000    
Final det =    -3.60000000000000000000E+02
```

You can insert more print lines until the whole mechanism becomes clear.

---

BTW, the code in [the Rossetta page](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Matrix_arithmetic#Fortran) seems much simpler than the OP's code by creating a sub-matrix directly as a local array. The simplified version of the code reads

```
recursive function det_rosetta( mat, n ) result( accum )
    integer :: n
    real    :: mat(n, n)
    real    :: submat(n-1, n-1), accum
    integer :: i, sgn

    if ( n == 1 ) then
        accum = mat(1,1)
    else
        accum = 0.0
        sgn = 1
        do i = 1, n
            submat( 1:n-1, 1:i-1 ) = mat( 2:n, 1:i-1 )
            submat( 1:n-1, i:n-1 ) = mat( 2:n, i+1:n )

            accum = accum + sgn * mat(1, i) * det_rosetta( submat, n-1 )
            sgn = - sgn
        enddo
    endif
end function
```

Note that the Laplace expansion is made along the first row, and that the `submat` is assigned using array sections. The assignment can also be written simply as

```
submat( :, :i-1 ) = mat( 2:, :i-1 )
submat( :, i: )   = mat( 2:, i+1: )
```

where the upper and lower bounds of the array sections are omitted (then, the declared values of upper and lower bounds are used by default). The latter form is used in the Rosetta page.

Comment: A really fantastic explaination, i've been studying this over the past few days and not only has your explaination given me a greater understanding of recursion but also further insight into array slicing, I appreciate the tme you have taken to supply me with this answer, I would upvote if I had the required reputation, I shall do when the time comes!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad if it helps :)